# Curl through list in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to iterate through a list to curl each one, this ultimately is to kick of a list of Jenkins jobs.

so i have a text file which contents is

```
ApplianceInsurance-Tests
BicycleInsurance-Tests
Breakdown-Tests
BridgingLoans-Tests
Broadband-Tests
Business-Loans
BusinessElectric-Tests
BusinessGas-Tests
```

and i am trying to create a loop in which i fire a curl command for each line in the txt file

```
for fn in `cat jenkins-lists.txt`; do "curl -X POST 'http://user:key@x.x.x.xxx:8080/job/$fn/build"; done
```

but i keep getting a error - No such file or directory.

Getting a little confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `do-done` body is quoted wrong. It should be:

```
curl -X POST "http://user:key@x.x.x.xxx:8080/job/$fn/build"
```

I'd also recommend:

```
while read -r fn; do
    curl -X POST "http://user:key@x.x.x.xxx:8080/job/$fn/build"
done < jenkins-list.txt
```

instead of `for fn in $(anything); do ...`. With the second way you don't 
have to worry about inadvertent globbing and the jenkins-list file may 
get nicely buffered instead of needing to be read all into memory at once (not that it matters for such a small file but why not have a technique that works well more or less regardless of file size?).

Comment: i am now getting the following error - curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL. So i am assuming the url is not getting created correctly with the parameter.

Comment: Well, then put an `echo ` before the `curl` command and see if your expectations match reality.

Comment: Its coming out as /buildX POST http://username:key@xx.x.x.xxx:8080/job/ApplianceInsurance-Tests how is the /build at the start?

Comment: @BrianMitchell With your file, `while read -r fn; do echo curl -X POST "http://user:key@x.x.x.xxx:8080/job/$fn/build"; done < jenkins-list.txt 
` generates https://pastebin.com/5UpMsBzG, no `/build` line in there.

Comment: There was something wrong with my txt file, it was created in notepad++ and copied across via winscp to my linux box. After copying the content and creating a new file within the linux terminal its echoing the lines correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If the error had come from curl, it would probably have been html-formatted.  The only way I can reproduce the error you describe is by cat-ing a non-existent file.

Double check the name of the `jenkins-lists.txt` file, and make sure your script is running in the same directory as the file.  Or use an absolute path to the file.